How To Get Linked PDFs To Open At Less Than 100%
I have a website with linked PDFs. I want them to display at 84% so that they fit one page at a time on my computer screen. The PDFs all fit when I view them in my PDF app, but when I upload them to my website they all display at 100% and are too big to fit on the monitor screen. I'm told that there is no way to fix this with HTML. Anybody have a suggestion?
I have Foxit for my PDF editor. I've tried for days to figure out how to save my files so that they will fit on one screen when they are uploaded to my website. They go from 84% in Foxit to 100% when uploaded.

If you want links to be viewed at Zoom=84% you can add that to the link like this for Firefox or Chromium's such as MSEdge.
It will not work for all browsers as some will ignore the request.
Try this in your web view.
https://dagrs.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/2020-01/sample.pdf#zoom=84%


Chromium's like Edge are more likely to respond to a request for a full height such as here, but again not all browsers "have to" nor are able to use that either.
Firefox requires the second syntax  , as it is down to browsers not the hyperlinks.
https://dagrs.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/2020-01/sample.pdf#view=FitV
https://dagrs.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/2020-01/sample.pdf#zoom=FitV


